# Why does SQLite require specific table join indexes for optimal performance

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

Why does SQLite require specific indexes on table joins for optimal query performance?
Why does a covering index not provide the same query performance?

Take the following tables and indexes for example:

```
Create table TableX
(    
 ColumnA int,
 ColumnB int
)

Create table TableY
(
 ColumnA int,
 ColumnB int
)

CREATE INDEX IX_TableX ON TableX(ColumnA, ColumnB);
CREATE INDEX IX_TableY ON TableY(ColumnA, ColumnB);
```

So here we have 2 tables, with 2 integer based columns and indexes across both columns. 
If I join these two tables across both columns A & B, the performance is good, however if I join them across only one column (such as A), the query plan shows it still uses the same covering index, but the query performance is vastly inferior.
Why is this? SqlServer does not seem to suffer from this issue.

Example (slower):

```
select distinct x.ColumnA, x.ColumnB 
from TableX x
inner join TableY y on y.ColumnA = x.ColumnA
```

Example (much faster):

```
select distinct x.ColumnA, x.ColumnB 
from TableX x
inner join TableY y on y.ColumnA = x.ColumnA 
                   and y.ColumnB = x.ColumnB
```

Comment: Did you eliminate the effect of the first query returning potentially many more rows than the second one? Other than that, ColumnA should make good use of the index, ColumnB not so much (as it is not a leading column)

Comment: What are the query plans for SQL Server and SQLite? Does either execute the query without going to tables at all (pure index scan/join)?

Comment: Thilo, the above is just an example of what I am continually running into. I dont actually select *, but instead specific columns and distinctly, but I'll update the examples thanks

Comment: It is very much possible that SQLServer has more complex query execution plans at its disposal. But you'll have to give the exact query and schema to get specific answers.

Comment: Regarding the queryplan, I've made sure in my queries that no table scans are done, so that always an index is used.

Comment: The query plan and even the VDBE code are essentially identical for both queries. So the only relevant difference is the number of result rows. With my test data, where the number of results is the same, the second query is a little bit slower.